# Highly unusual mongoose behaviour: find() returning only one document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been working with mongoose for a while and I am currently stuck with this problem:

I have a dynamic MongoDB database on which a an express end-point batch inserts records using `Model.collection.insert`. The insertion is perfect, I can see all the documents by query using mongo shell and the document count is as expected.

Here is format of the documents that are inserted:

```
[  
   {  
      "disk":"Aff90",
      "graph":
       {
         "Q1":{  
            "frequency":21
         },
         "Q2":{  
            "frequency":13
         },
         "Q3":{  
            "frequency":35
         },
         "Q4":{  
            "frequency":24
         }
      },
      "sales": 987,
      "deep_discount": 50,
      "demand_score": 3.4
   },
   {  
      "disk":"B721",
      "graph":
       {
         "Q1":{  
            "frequency":98
         },
         "Q2":{  
            "frequency":129
         },
         "Q3":{  
            "frequency":812
         },
         "Q4":{  
            "frequency":240
         }
      },
      "sales": 2017,
      "deep_discount": 80,
      "demand_score": 7.4
   },//and so on(about 1000 documents) 
]
```

However, when I use my express end-point to query back that data, it only returns the first element. I have not encountered this particular problem with mongoose yet and am unable to find a solution on the web.

Express API code for the retrieval:

```
router.post('/end-point',  function(req, res, next) {

  model.find({}, {"_id":0}, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
      if(data.length){
        res.json(data);
      }
   });
});
```

Can someone help me understand what the issue is about and how I could solve it?

Comment: On a whim, I wonder if this could have something to do with the {"_id": 0} there. I know that's valid syntax, but what happens if you remove it?

Comment: Same result. @Harangue

Comment: Since your using `find()` I dont think you need those params if you just want to get all the data. Have you tried `model.find().exec(function(err, data){  })` instead?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Works fine on my local machine, only returning one result in production server.